# How to convert rows to columns according to the content of a column

Tags: csv, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a csv/xls file with 50,000 rows and 3 columns in the following format:

```
Text01 | text02 | Tag
Text1  | text2  | Tag1
Text3  | text4  | Tag1
Text5  | text6  | Tag1
Text7  | text8  | Tag2
Text9  | text10 | Tag2
Text11 | text12 | Tag3
```

Etc
I want to convert it to the following format:

```
Tag  | text1 | text2 | text3 | etc
Tag1 | Text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 | text5 | text6
```

Etc

Update

I tried a solution previously proposed by @player0 using google sheet formula and it only works if the tag column contains a single word and not several words :

In conclusion and more clearly I am looking for a solution that allows me to group together the rows that have a common column knowing that the number of rows is variable.

[image: @player0 solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B<>"", 
 {IF(COUNTIFS(D2:D, D2:D, ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))=1, "♥"&D2:D, )&"♦"&B2:B, "♦"&C2:C}, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you for the solution, but don't work for me https://prnt.sc/pqr6sc

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B<>""; 
     {IF(COUNTIFS(D2:D; D2:D; ROW(D2:D); "<="&ROW(D2:D))=1; "♥"&D2:D; )&"♦"&B2:B\ "♦"&C2:C}; ))
     ;;999^99));;999^99); "♥")); "♦"))`

Comment: Hi, still not working with error message to add new columns.. UPDATE : i start a new sheets and its work but compy only the value of tag1 tag 1 tag1..

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: well, you did not change the references to point to your actual data

Comment: use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:A<>""; {IF(COUNTIFS(C2:C; C2:C; ROW(C2:C); "<="&ROW(C2:C))=1; "♥"&C2:C; )&"♦"&A2:A\ "♦"&B2:B}; )) ;;999^99));;999^99); "♥")); "♦"))`